# PHP Query using PDO Showing Outside of Table

Tags: php

So I have a foreach loop as such.

```
foreach ($stmt as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['user_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$all_users->getUserStatus($row['Enabled'])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['last_login']."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<button type='button' class='btn btn-text-color'>"."Show"."</button>"." "."<button type='button' class='btn btn-text-color'>"."Edit"."</button>"."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' name='selectAll'>"."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

As you can see I am using to retrieve information from the database to put in a html table. However the line below is retrieving the correct information expect it is showing outside of the table.

This is the line that is causing the error.

```
echo "<td>".$all_users->getUserStatus($row['Enabled'])."</td>";
```

Here is the function it is calling.

```
function getUserStatus($userStatus)
        {

            if($userStatus == 0)
            {
                echo  "No";
            }
            else if ($userStatus == 5)
            {
                echo "Yes";
            }

        }
```

Help as I am a noob to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return` instead of `echo` in `getUserStatus()`

```
    function getUserStatus($userStatus)
    {

        if($userStatus == 0)
        {
            return  "No";
        }
        else if ($userStatus == 5)
        {
            return "Yes";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a bunch.